# How to pass database queryset objects from class based views(class SignUp(generic.CreateView)) to templates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

I used django custom user creation method to sign up users, its working fine. But how to pass objects to templates in my class SignUp. I'm new to class based view. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To pass context, you can write

```
context_object_name = 'username'
```

Now think like you are making a To Do  app and want to print the Tasks as per their
You can then do the following inside your class based view,

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context['count'] = context['tasks'].count()
```

In this way, you can write the database queryset in class based views.

If you want a perfect guide or source code to learn the django authentication i.e. login and logout user functions, I suggest you to go once through this tutorial, It is a todo list app which will cover your doubts

[To Do list app with django authentication and queryset in class based views](https://github.com/divanov11/Django-To-Do-list-with-user-authentication)

The sourcecode for the above is here:

[Source code](https://github.com/divanov11/Django-To-Do-list-with-user-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method in `SignUp` class, like this:

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(SignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['your_qset'] = YourModel.objects.all()
       return context
```

and use it in template:

```
{% for obj in your_qset %}
   {{ obj }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried it but it shows nothing. Instead of passing my models i tried this also.. context['test'] = 'hello world' and in my html i used {{ test }}. still it shows nothing. So put a simple print statement after get_context_data() that print statement is also not showing(in the terminal). what might be reason ?

Comment: Not sure what is happening here. Because `get_context_data` will always get call when you are making `GET` request to the url.

Comment: Maybe can you share what you have tried in the question please?

Comment: class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
     form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
     template_name = 'signup.html'
     print('testing1')

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('testing2') 
        context = super(SignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tasks'] = Document.objects.all() 
        return context

Comment: Sorry, its hard to read. But can you try print function inside `get_context_data` method? Also what gets printed when you try `print(Document.objects.all())` in the view?